# Naming downloaded files in Python

Tags: python

Hello stackoverflow angels.

I'm trying to name some images with the header names as a prefix. Here's the code

```
import requests
import itertools
import pandas as pd

lista = pd.read_excel("Link_img_ferplast.xlsx")

lista = lista.values.tolist()
lista2 = list(itertools.chain(*lista))

for img in lista2:
    file_name = (img.split('/')[-1])
    print(f"This is the file name: {file_name}")

    r = requests.get(img, stream=True)

    if r.status_code == 200:

        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)
    else:

        broken_images.append(img)
```

The dataset:
[Link_img_ferplast.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq23P.png)

I'm also having some issues with the following error:

**line 11, in 
file_name = (img.split('/')[-1])
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'**

This is stopping the code, after downloading some images.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you have missing values (NaN) in lista2, which are considered float objects.  Try to check if your values are missing before spliting:

```py
for img in lista2:
    if pd.isnull(img):
        continue  # continue with next element in list2
    file_name = (img.split('/')[-1])
```